# When no routes are found in android maps polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I m using following code for direction from one place to other to get polyline. Between some places, No routes are found and null value is passed to addPolyline.  How to avoid this kind of situation. Is there something which has to be done. Or some other method by which we deal with this situation. Your help will be appreciated.

```
class DirectionsJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
List<List<HashMap>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

List<List<HashMap>> routes = new ArrayList<>() ;
JSONArray jRoutes;
JSONArray jLegs;
JSONArray jSteps;

try {

    jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

    /** Traversing all routes */
    for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
        jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
        List path = new ArrayList<>();

        /** Traversing all legs */
        for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
            jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

            /** Traversing all steps */
            for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                String polyline = "";
                polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                /** Traversing all points */
                for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                    hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                    hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                    path.add(hm);
                }
            }
            routes.add(path);
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e){
}


return routes;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use value of `overview_polyline` tag of JSON response to get whole path in [encoded format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) and than decode it to `List<LatLng>`:

```
...
JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(jsonStringBuilder.toString());
JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("routes");

if (jsonRoutes.length() >= 1) {
    JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject overviewPolyline = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
    String overviewPolylineEncodedPoints = overviewPolyline.getString("points");
    routePoints = decodePoly(overviewPolylineEncodedPoints);
}
...

//
// Method to decode polyline points
// Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Also you can use [`PolyUtil`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) class to decode encoded polylines.